# SQL 2005: Discover all client connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, logging, database-connection

I have a project to inventory an SQL Server. Part of this project includes discovering every IP that makes a connection to this SQL Server. It is an internal SQL Server with several other programs running on other servers that access this SQL server. Because this server's IP address is going to be changed, all of those other programs will have to updated with the new address. Plus the boss just wants a diagram of everything running on this server and everything connecting to it.

My initial inclination would be to setup logon triggers to capture the client IP address and port and write it to table. I am unfamiliar with logon triggers and have read that they present dangers to the server.

What is the best way that I can discover who all is connecting to and using this server?

Answer (score 0):

Running the stored procedure `sp_who` will tell you about the machines connected to a SQL server instance.

Comment: This does not provide client IP address and port information like what is found in sys.dm_exec_connections. Of course, I need to track connections over time, not just active connections.